# Don't integrate user information into your domain model?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have read some articles about the new simple membership provider in .NET 4.5
But I dont really understand why I should store the user information in a different place not in the domain?

Anybody can explain me what the advantages and disadvantages are?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [an article on a related question](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/03/05/38558/). In short, doing so makes your authentication tightly coupled with your domain model, which is probably wrong. You should separate the concerns of domain-specific user data, which probably belongs in your domain model, and authentication, which doesn't.